KeyvFile cache invalidation doesn't work as expected
I have Keyv with KeyvFile with Singleton wrapper.
class CacheDatabaseInstance {
  private static createCacheDatabase(): Keyv {
    // ttl: undefined - infinite duration
    return new Keyv({
      store: new KeyvFile({ filename: cacheDatabaseFilePath }),
    });
  }

  public static getCacheDatabase(): Keyv {
    return Singleton.getInstance<Keyv>('CacheDatabaseInstance', () =>
      CacheDatabaseInstance.createCacheDatabase()
    );
  }
}

I have 2 problems with this:

When I invalidate a key, that key and value aren't removed from .json file to decrease file size. When I invalidate entire cache .json file should be empty but actually it's not, nothing is ever removed, it can only grow. Key is invalidated but it's not removed from the file to save space.

await getCacheDatabase().clear();


Soemtimes in Docker invalidation fails silently. I call:

await getCacheDatabase().clear();

but it still reads outdated values. I have Singleton wrapper so I am certain I call .clear() on the original instance.
Any ideas how to solve this, what could cause this, is this library buggy or Im doing something incorrectly?
For more context, here are instance definitions:
https://github.com/nemanjam/hn-new-jobs/blob/main/libs/keyv.ts
And here is cache invalidation:
https://github.com/nemanjam/hn-new-jobs/blob/main/modules/parser/calls.ts
